# Creating a MACRO to a specific array position in C

Tags: c, arrays, macros

I've got some problems with the below code (similar version), where I created a MACRO to a specific position of array in C. However, I can't access the Macro.

```
 unsigned int rx_data[2][2];
 #define rx_1_data (rx_data[0]);

    int main()
    {
      if(rx_1_data > 0)
      {
        rx_1_data = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        rx_1_data = 99;
      }
    }
```

The compiler inform to me the following errors messages:
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token

Does someone have any idea about the correct way to do the access to the array declared in MACRO?

Comment: Don't put `;` at the end of a macro definition.

Answer (score 1):

Macros in C expand using very simple rules, so the resulting code looks roughly like:

```
if((rx_data[0]); > 0)
```

That's clearly a syntax error. Make your macro more minimal to avoid syntax issues, like specifically remove the incorrect `;`. `#define` statements *do not* need termination that way, they are handled differently from regular code.

A macro like this just makes your code extremely frustrating to read. Don't do this unless you must. `rx_data[0]` isn't even more typing, you're saving nothing here.